# Proper TLS Certificate Exception Handling Logic

Tags: security, ssl, hash, x509

I would like to know what are the recommended best practices and validation logic for handling TLS certificate exceptions, similar to OpenSSH's known_hosts file. I know the best practices would be to have certificates that can be validated automatically, but here I am talking of the cases where the certificate cannot be validated and the user wants to accept it anyway. I would like to know the following:

1) What information should be stored in each entry
2) How the information should be stored for secure access
3) How the hashing of the certificate should be performed

AFAIK, the known_hosts file contains the following information:

```
<hostname> <certificate hash>
```

The biggest problem I can see with this approach is when we connect to the same hostname with different ports, which happens frequently when using port forwarding to map to different machines behind NAT. In this case, extra information should probably be stored this way:

```
<hostname>:<port> <certificate hash>
```

As for storing the information itself, the known_hosts file is normally stored in a user directory with owner write permissions. Is this considered "secure"? I mean, any process running as the current user could just add new exceptions for certificates the user has not explicitly accepted.

As for the hashing, I assume it should be performed on the entire X.509 certificate? I just wanted to check, since the X.509 certificate has the "TBSCertificate" structure in it, which excludes the the signature. I am not sure what should really be done here. Also, I would like to know the current recommended algorithms for hashing the certificate for exception purposes.

Thank you in advance for your recommendations on the question!